# Error parsing response from JSON adwhirl

Tags: android, admob

I just started getting this error with adwhirl.

```
 E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be
 fatal.
E/AdWhirl SDK(  345): org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArra
y cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

What does this mean and is it an error on my end? Or is it something that happens with adwhirl? Any solutions to fix this?

Comment: looks like you are trying to convert the Array into a JsonObject. Kindly check the object type before converting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AdWhirl servers also went down yesterday.  This was likely not on your end.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are trying to convert the received JSONObject into the JSONArray.

Initially you have to create a JSONObject like:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
```

And then get the JSONArray from that jsonObj as:

```
JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("arrayname");
```